# Dividing text file lines to two different tables of a database

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, text-files

I am sorry if I wasn't clear yeasterday, What I am trying to do is take a text file, line by line and depending on what the line starts with will determine what table to send it to. I am having issues finding the best (most efficient) way of sending certain lines that start with a word or "[" to a certain table. This is a example the text file I am loading, it is logs and the Exception, Message and Source can be anywhere through out the text file. The lines that start with "[" goes to (LogTable) and the lines that start with "Exception" are going to (ExceptionTable) but every "Exception" is connected to the previous Log line, so I am also looking for a way to connect the two so they can be linked in the database. I am trying to loop through each line in the file and determine which table it needs to go to with linq query and save changes to the mySQL database.

```
[2012-07-05 00:01:07,008]  [INFO ] [MessageManager]  [3780] () [] [Starting     ProcessNewMessageEvent]
[2012-07-05 00:01:07,008]  [INFO ] [MessageManager]  [3780] () [] [Method: RegValue]
[2012-07-05 00:01:07,008]  [DEBUG] [MessageManager]  [3780] () [] [reg: InstallPath]

Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException
Message: There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Source: mscorlib
[2012-07-04 23:55:59,598]  [INFO ] [MessageManager]  [6616] () [] [Method: RegValue]
[2012-07-04 23:55:59,598]  [DEBUG] [MessageManager]  [6616] () [] [reg: InstallPath]
```

This code is not looping it will perform the first loop then it get caught in the last section with "grougquery" query and doesn't loop through the whole "for" loop, so when it gets to a "Exception:" line it throws an Exception. Is there a more efficient way around this than what I am doing here? A different way I haven't found? Thanks again

```
                foreach (string s in filePaths)
                {
                  string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(s);

                  for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                  {
                      if (lines[i].Contains("Exception:"))
                      {

                          var exQuery = from exMessage in lines
                                        let logRecord = exMessage.Split(':')
                                        select new ExTable()

                                        {
                                            ExlogException = logRecord[i],
                                            ExlogMessage = logRecord[i + 1],
                                            ExlogSource = logRecord[i + 2],

                                        };
                          foreach (var item in exQuery)
                          {
                              exception ex = new exception();


                              ex.LogException = item.ExlogException;
                              ex.LogMessage = item.ExlogMessage;
                              ex.LogSource = item.ExlogSource;
                              ex.LogServerStackTrace = item.ExlogServerStackTrace;
                              ex.LogExRethrown = item.ExlogRethrown;

                          }

                      }
                      else if (lines[i].Contains("["))
                      {

                          var groupQuery = from date in lines
                                           let logRecord = date.Split('[', ']', '(', ')')
                                           select new OLog()

                                           {
                                               OlogDate = logRecord[1],
                                               OlogLevel = logRecord[3],
                                               OlogLogger = logRecord[5],
                                               OlogThread = logRecord[7],
                                               OlogProperty = logRecord[9],
                                               OlogMethod = logRecord[11],
                                               OlogException = logRecord[12],

                                           };


                          foreach (var item in groupQuery)
                          {
                              temp temp = new temp();

                              temp.logDate = item.OlogDate;
                              temp.logLevel = item.OlogLevel;
                              temp.logLogger = item.OlogLogger;
                              temp.logThread = item.OlogThread;
                              temp.logProperty = item.OlogProperty;
                              temp.logMethod = item.OlogMethod;
                              temp.logException = item.OlogException;

                              logEntity.temps.AddObject(temp);
                          }

                      }
                  }
                          logEntity.SaveChanges();
               }
```

Comment: `this is the code that isn't working.` How is it not working?

Comment: It is not working because he does not loop for each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you are trying to do ... in a more linqy way than just a for loop.

Note, this example was run in LinqPad (linqpad.com) which I recommend for working with linq code.  It gave the expected results.

```
void Main()
{
    string [] lines = {
"[2012-07-05 00:01:07,008]  [INFO ] [MessageManager]  [3780] () [] [Starting     ProcessNewMessageEvent]",
"[2012-07-05 00:01:07,008]  [INFO ] [MessageManager]  [3780] () [] [Method: RegValue]",
"[2012-07-05 00:01:07,008]  [DEBUG] [MessageManager]  [3780] () [] [reg: InstallPath]",
@"Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException
Message: There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Source: mscorlib",
"[2012-07-04 23:55:59,598]  [INFO ] [MessageManager]  [6616] () [] [Method: RegValue]",
"[2012-07-04 23:55:59,598]  [DEBUG] [MessageManager]  [6616] () [] [reg: InstallPath]"
    };

       var exceptions = lines.Where(l => l.Contains("Exception:"))
                          .Select(line => 
                          { 
                             var items = line.Split(':');
                             var result = new  
                                          {
                                             OlogException = items.ElementAtOrDefault(1),
                                             OlogMessage =   items.ElementAtOrDefault(2),
                                             OlogSource = items.ElementAtOrDefault(3),
                                             OlogServerStackTrace = items.ElementAtOrDefault(4)
                                          };
                             return result;
                          });

    var groups = lines.Where(l => l.StartsWith("["))
                      .Select(line => 
                       { 
                          var items = line.Split('[', ']', '(', ')');
                          var result = new 
                                       {
                                          OlogDate = items.ElementAtOrDefault(1),
                                          OlogLevel = items.ElementAtOrDefault(3),
                                          OlogLogger = items.ElementAtOrDefault(5),
                                          OlogThread = items.ElementAtOrDefault(7),
                                          OlogProperty = items.ElementAtOrDefault(9),
                                          OlogMethod = items.ElementAtOrDefault(11),
                                          OlogException = items.ElementAtOrDefault(13)
                                        };
                          return result;
                       });

  exceptions.Dump();
  groups.Dump();


}
```

Comment: I am coming up with two errors, one with the exception query at (.Select)(error: 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Select') does not  and another at the group query at the (.Filter)(error: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Filter') Just wondering if you know why it might give me an error like that. Thanks

Comment: @SamanthaIrenSweeney - Ok fixed, I should have been using `Where()` in both those cases, as you can see from the new code.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

use SSIS to make your integration, it will be easier and it helps you to split text file
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3172.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting by lines and then by ':', it looks to me like your Exception spans 3 lines and thus 3 different values in your lines array so your second split isn't going to work as expected.

One way to accomplish what I think you're trying to accomplish is to iterate through the lines array and then handle the cases as you encounter them, something like this:

```
foreach (string s in filePaths) {
//goes through each line in each file
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(s);

for (int i=0;i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (line[i].Contains("Exception:"))
    {
        // Handle line[i] as Exception, line[i+1] as Message, line[i+2] as Source
    }
    else if (line[i].Contains("["))
    {
        // Same as you had before
    }
}
// same as before
```

}